# Is the solution of the Poisson equation unique for following example

Tags: electrostatics, potential

For the Laplace equation we have
$$\Delta \varphi = -\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_r \epsilon_0}$$
I know that the solution is not unique, since $\phi$ can also a solution.
$$\phi = \varphi + f $$
for $\Delta f=0$

However, my professor said that $f = e^x\cos(y)+z$ is also a solution, even though the Laplacian is not zero. 
Am I missing something?

Comment: ... the Laplacian *is* zero...

Comment: @Philip I blundered there, my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given
$$
f = e^x \cos y + z.
$$
The Laplacian operator can be written in full as
$$
\Delta f = \left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}\right)e^x\cos y + z,
$$
which is pretty easy to apply, resulting in the expression
$$
\Delta f = e^x\cos y - e^x\cos y
$$
which is zero.

Comment: My bad, since I saw e^x I didn't even bother calculating it because I thought the terms were going to be =/= 0.

Comment: Bad move! :) Remember, the Laplacian is often zero because the derivatives *cancel each other* in very specific ways :) Read up about [Harmonic Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function).